# Unable to use Except in update postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am facing a problem when I am trying to use Except with an update statement, It is required because I don't want to use <> for each field when updating a record.

Here is the real example where I am trying to use except

```
    update_existing_item_sales AS(
    UPDATE daily_item_sales 
    SET sales_amt = jd.sales_amt,
    sales_qty = jd.sales_qty, 
    sales_prc=jd.sales_prc,
    sales_promo_amt = jd.sales_promo_amt, 
    sales_promo_qty = jd.sales_promo_qty, 
    discount_amt = jd.discount_amt, 
    discount_qty = jd.discount_qty, 
    coupon_amt = jd.coupon_amt, 
    coupon_qty = jd.coupon_qty, 
    price_override_amt = jd.price_override_amt, 
    price_override_qty = jd.price_override_qty, 
    return_amt = jd.return_amt, 
    return_qty = jd.return_qty, 
    item_scanned = jd.item_scanned, 
    item_keyed = jd.item_keyed 
    FROM updated_Item_data jd 
    WHERE daily_item_sales.id = jd.id
    EXCEPT (select jd.* from updated_Item_data jd 
        INNER JOIN daily_item_sales on 
    WHERE daily_item_sales.id = jd.id 
    AND daily_item_sales.sales_amt = jd.sales_amt 
    AND daily_item_sales.sales_qty = jd.sales_qty 
    AND daily_item_sales.sales_promo_amt = jd.sales_promo_amt
    AND daily_item_sales.sales_promo_qty = jd.sales_promo_qty
    AND daily_item_sales.discount_amt = jd.discount_amt
    AND daily_item_sales.discount_qty = jd.discount_qty
    AND daily_item_sales.coupon_amt = jd.coupon_amt
    AND daily_item_sales.coupon_qty = jd.coupon_qty
    AND daily_item_sales.price_override_amt = jd.price_override_amt
    AND daily_item_sales.price_override_qty = jd.price_override_qty
    AND daily_item_sales.return_amt = jd.return_amt
    AND daily_item_sales.return_qty = jd.return_qty
    AND daily_item_sales.item_scanned = jd.item_scanned
    AND daily_item_sales.item_keyed = jd.item_keyed)
)
```

The error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPT"

                                            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 37
```

Comment: `except` combines the result of two **SELECT** commands, just like UNION or INTERSECT. Using it to combine an UPDATE with a SELECT makes no sense.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a `FROM updated_Item_data jd 
    WHERE daily_item_sales.id = jd.id and jd is distinct from daily_item_sales`?

Comment: Where does `updated_Item_data` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the query as follows:

```
update app_user 
set deleted = false 
where end_timestamp is not null
```

Comment: I can go with this way but I have to use except somewhere else, so please provide answer with Except only

Comment: Why do you have to use it? Check out the syntax for update, the only place, where you can put `except` is the nested query: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html

Comment: @Anil if you have to use `except` "somewhere else", then show us that "somewhere else", not some unrelated code.

Comment: Here is the real example where I am trying to use except

Comment: @Andronicus I am updating one table by using a set of records(CTE) and I don't want to update those records which are exactly same as in the table

Answer (score 1):

`EXCEPT` is a set-based operator -- like `UNION`, `UNION ALL`, and `INTERSECT` -- that connects result sets generated by `SELECT`.  It does not make sense with `UPDATE`.

But, it is easily replaced using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with u as (
    UPDATE daily_item_sales 
        SET sales_amt = jd.sales_amt,
            sales_qty = jd.sales_qty, 
            sales_prc=jd.sales_prc,
            sales_promo_amt = jd.sales_promo_amt, 
            sales_promo_qty = jd.sales_promo_qty, 
            discount_amt = jd.discount_amt, 
            discount_qty = jd.discount_qty, 
            coupon_amt = jd.coupon_amt, 
            coupon_qty = jd.coupon_qty, 
            price_override_amt = jd.price_override_amt, 
            price_override_qty = jd.price_override_qty, 
            return_amt = jd.return_amt, 
            return_qty = jd.return_qty, 
            item_scanned = jd.item_scanned, 
            item_keyed = jd.item_keyed 
        FROM updated_Item_data jd 
        WHERE daily_item_sales.id = jd.id AND
              NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM daily_item_sales dis
                          WHERE dis.id = jd.id AND 
                                dis.sales_amt = jd.sales_amt AND  
                                dis.sales_qty = jd.sales_qty AND 
                                dis.sales_promo_amt = jd.sales_promo_amt AND 
                                dis.sales_promo_qty = jd.sales_promo_qty AND 
                                dis.discount_amt = jd.discount_amt AND 
                                dis.discount_qty = jd.discount_qty AND 
                                dis.coupon_amt = jd.coupon_amt AND 
                                dis.coupon_qty = jd.coupon_qty AND 
                                dis.price_override_amt = jd.price_override_amt AND
                                dis.price_override_qty = jd.price_override_qty AND
                                dis.return_amt = jd.return_amt AND
                                dis.return_qty = jd.return_qty AND
                                dis.item_scanned = jd.item_scanned AND
                                dis.item_keyed = jd.item_keyed
                               )
. . .
```

That said, this is probably better handled using `ON CONFLICT` with a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Could be simplified as

```
update daily_item_sales as t set
    (sales_amt, sales_qty, sales_prc, ...) = (s.sales_amt, s.sales_qty, s.sales_prc, ...)
from updated_Item_data as s
where
    t.id = s.id and
    (t.sales_amt, t.sales_qty, t.sales_prc, ...) is distinct from (s.sales_amt, s.sales_qty, s.sales_prc, ...)
```